# Protect DataSet/DataTable file using data protection API

Tags: c#, .net, dataset

I am writing [DataTable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable(v=vs.110).aspx) into XML using [DataTable.WriteXml](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.writexml(v=vs.110).aspx) method which is latter loaded back into my application. I would like to protect my xml files using native .NET Framework data protection API which can be found [here.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229741(v=vs.100).aspx)

**Question:** How can I store my DataTable in xml using WinDPAPI?

Comment: Just to make sure, the API doesn't protect the "file", but encrypts the "data". Is this what you had in mind?

Comment: Correct I need somehow turn DataTable into byte array protect it and persist it into file.